# android system data cache wipe does not delete everything

Tags: android

My phone is behaving odd, it freezes and stutters all of the time even after wiping and installing several different ROMs.

I noticed that there are still files inside /cache and /system. I was wondering if it is safe to delete these?

Comment: When you install a new ROM,did you keep the user data?I think it is the apps that slows your phone down,not the ROM.

Comment: i deleted everything! data, system, cache, will now try fix permissions

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!! After wiping with the "rm -f" option i see that the phone is now blazing fast again and even the home screen is different, it only goes to show that files were not being wiped using simple format (in twrp and clockworkmod)